# SOL2/C++ - Lua beginner, is it possible to pass Lua Tables between Lua files?

Tags: c++, lua

Currently, I'm trying to set up Sol2, and I was trying to use a Lua file that needs to access another Lua file.
I have no problems with Sol2 in general, but when I try to use two files together my program stops working. The Lua code should be right (...?, I also tried using `test2 = a.x.test`, and `require('a')`), so I'm guessing I need to change something because of Sol2?

a.lua:

```lua
local x = {
test = 1
}
```

b.lua:

```lua
local a = require 'a'
local options = {
test2 = a.test
}
```

C++:

```cpp
sol::state lua;
lua.script_file("b.lua");
int x = lua[b][test2];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables are not seen outside their files. So:

Append this line to `a.lua`:

```
return x
```

Append this line to `b.lua`:

```
return options
```

Now you need to fix the C++ side. Probably something like this, but I don't know Sol:

```
auto result = lua.script_file("b.lua");
int x = result["test2"];
```